# Stalks at points in the fibre of scheme morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes and $y\in Y$ be a point. Then we can define the fibre of $f$ at $y$ by $X_y:=X\times_{Y}k(y)$. My question is the following: let $x\in X_y$ be a point. Then what can we say about $\mathcal{O}_{X_y,x}$, the stalk of $X_y$ at $x$?

Thank you!

Comment: It should probably be clear what it is when you Think about the construction of the product. That is, in affine neighbourhoods of points it is the tensor product over the ring determining a neighbourhood of y. As such the stalk is just the localization at x of that tensor product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak m_y\subset \mathcal O_{Y,y}$ be the maximal ideal. Then the local ring you are looking for is
$$\mathcal O_{X_y,x}=\mathcal O_{X,x}\otimes_{\mathcal O_{Y,y}}k(y)=\frac {\mathcal O_{X,x}}{\mathfrak m_y \mathcal O_{X,x}}               $$
The proof consists in reducing to the affine case.
The affine case is then handled in Matsumura, Commutative Ring Theory, pages 47-48.